# Column widths changing when exporting from SSRS to Excel

Tags: excel, reporting-services, sql-server-2014

I have a simple SSRS report which contains a single table with a header row, footer row and any number of detail rows.  The width of the report and table is 7 inches and the report has .5 inch margins all the way around.  But when I export this report to Excel, the width of each column is increased by about 8%, which causes the report to exceed 7.5 inches and overflow to a second page when printing it.  I've simplified the report so that no extra or hidden columns are generated in Excel, but it still has this problem.  I know I can use Globals!RenderFormat.Name to determine if it's being generated in Excel, but since I can't use an expression in column widths, that doesn't appear to be of any help.

How do I get SSRS to maintain the same column widths when exporting to Excel?

Comment: I found a work-around, but it's not the ideal solution.  In Excel select Page Layout in the menu, and change Width to 1 Page.  This shrinks everything when printing to fit on one page.  If there's a better solution I'd be glad to see it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that the dependency of the column widths when exporting to excel is linear. This is the reason why I made simple linear regression and I have the following results:

If you need column width of X when exporting to excel, you should use the following formula for width in inches in SSRS (Y)

Y = 0.072810 * X  +  0.055624467

Or of you need column width of 10 for the exported excel file, the width in inches in SSRS(Y) should be:

Y = 0.072810 * 10  +  0.055624467 so we have Y = 0.7837